# Error running an Docker container or docker compose with postgres, golang and Debian 11, Agora appbuilder backend

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, agora.io

I spun up a Debian 11 EC2 on AWS, and installed postgres 14.5 on it and docker and docker compose on it.I added a superuser to postgres of "admin' with a password. I created my docker-compose.yml file and a .env file.

When I try to use the docker-compose.yml file, I get:

```
sudo docker compose up -d
services.database.environment must be a mapping
```

When I build my docker container with

```
sudo docker build . -t tvappbuilder:latest
```

and then try to run it with:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 tvappbuilder:latest --env-file .env -it
Config Path .
4:47PM INF server/utils/logging.go:105 > logging configured fileLogging=true fileName=app-builder-logs logDirectory=./logs maxAgeInDays=0 maxBackups=0 maxSizeMB=0
4:47PM FTL server/cmd/video_conferencing/server.go:71 > Error initializing database error="pq: Could not detect default username. Please provide one explicitly"
```

Here are the dockers so far:

```
sudo docker image list
REPOSITORY     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>         <none>    6e5f035abda5   18 hours ago    1.82GB
tvappbuilder   latest    6166e24a47e0   21 hours ago    21.8MB
<none>         <none>    cedcaf2facd1   21 hours ago    1.82GB
hello-world    latest    feb5d9fea6a5   12 months ago   13.3kB
golang         1.15.1    9f495162f677   2 years ago     839MB
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: 3.7
services:
    server:
        container_name: server
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - database
        ports:
           - 8080:8080
        environment:
            - APP_ID: $APP_ID
            - APP_CERTIFICATE: $APP_CERTIFICATE
            - CUSTOMER_ID: $CUSTOMER_ID
            - CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE: $CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE
            - BUCKET_NAME: $BUCKET_NAME
            - BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY: $BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY
            - BUCKET_ACCESS_SECRET: $BUCKET_ACCESS_SECRET
            - CLIENT_ID: $CLIENT_ID
            - CLIENT_SECRET: $CLIENT_SECRET
            - PSTN_USERNAME: $PSTN_USERNAME
            - PSTN_PASSWORD: $PSTN_PASSWORD
            - SCHEME: $SCHEME
            - ALLOWED_ORIGIN: ""
            - ENABLE_NEWRELIC_MONITORING: false
            - RUN_MIGRATION: true
            - DATABASE_URL: postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@database:5432/$POSTGRES_DB?sslmode=disable

    database:
        container_name: server_database
        image: postgres-14.5
        restart: always
        hostname: database
        environment: 
            - POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            - POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
## Using Dockerfile from the following post: https://medium.com/@petomalina/using-go-mod-download-to-speed-up-golang-docker-builds-707591336888

FROM golang:1.15.1 as build-env

# All these steps will be cached
RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server
COPY go.mod . 
COPY go.sum .

# Get dependancies - will also be cached if we won't change mod/sum
RUN go mod download
# COPY the source code as the last step
COPY . .

# Build the binary
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o /go/bin/server /server/cmd/video_conferencing

# Second step to build minimal image
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build-env /go/bin/server /go/bin/server
COPY --from=build-env /server/config.json config.json

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/server"]
```

and here is the .env file:

```
ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=0
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<correct pswd for admin>
POSTGRES_DB=tvappbuilder
APP_ID=<my real app ID>
APP_CERTIFICATE=<my real app cert>
CUSTOMER_ID=<my real ID>
CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE=<my real cert>
RECORDING_REGION=0
BUCKET_NAME=<my bucket name>
BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY=<my real key>
BUCKET_ACCESS_SECRET=<my real secret>
CLIENT_ID=
CLIENT_SECRET=
PSTN_USERNAME=
PSTN_PASSWORD=
PSTN_ACCOUNT=
PSTN_EMAIL=
SCHEME=esports1_agora
ENABLE_SLACK_OAUTH=0
SLACK_CLIENT_ID=
SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
ENABLE_GOOGLE_OAUTH=0
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
ENABLE_MICROSOFT_OAUTH=0
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID=
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET=
APPLE_CLIENT_ID=
APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY=
APPLE_KEY_ID=
APPLE_TEAM_ID=
ENABLE_APPLE_OAUTH=0
PAPERTRAIL_API_TOKEN=<my real token>
```

According to this: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq
I probably should not need to use pq, and instead use postgres directly, but it appears it
was set up this way.

Many thanks for any pointers!

Comment: "and installed postgres 14.5" you appear you have installed postgres on the server AND you are running postgres under docker? (do one or the other). Ref the compose error remove the `-` from in front of the environment variable lines (or use `=` instead of `:`) - see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment).

Comment: Yes removing the '-' worked well. Also yes It looks like the docker-compose did install postgres again. Thank you! If you make this the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments there are a number of issues with your setup.

The first is the error `services.database.environment must be a mapping` when running `docker compose up -d`. This is caused by lines like `- APP_ID: $APP_ID` in your `docker-compose.yml` - use either `APP_ID: $APP_ID` or `- APP_ID=$APP_ID` as per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment).

A further issue is that you installed Postgres on the bare OS and are then using a postgres container. You only need to do one or the other (but if using docker you will want to use a volume or mount for the Postgres data (otherwise it will be lose when the container is rebuilt).

There are probably further issues but the above should get you started.